# "Low Memory Space" but my space is plenty

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, insufficient-memory

As of right now i have 144mb on external, and 44 on internal. But i can't download a 8mb app? I fixed it once but i had to do a lot of stuff to it and I'm only 14 so yeah not a tech wiz. Its getting really annoying. Help?

When i clear the data for Google Play Store Services and Google Play Store (application manager > all) the low memory space notification thing foes away for like 10seconds and then comes back

Comment: u download must be on internal by default

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. If not how do i do that?

Comment: move some apps to sdard from settings

Comment: Cant do that. I have a Samsung Galaxy Exhibit

Comment: ok from where r u downloading apps?

Comment: Google Play Store

Answer (score 1):

Android leaves some space for system updates, usually 10% (I'm not sure if this number), so if your free space becomes lower than that, it says you are running out of storage space.

There are methods for increasing internal storage by using a second partition on your SD Card and mounting it using [Link2Sd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dlink2sd&pcampaignid=APPU_TU34U4XwGNOSuATQyICICA). (Note: you need root for this)